# overlay content on backstretch

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-backstretch

I want to add a div with some title over the JQuery Backstretch images. The code looks like:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
    <div class="imgs">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here the inner div is used for backstretch. If I add any content prior to that within outer div, (like below) the stretch is not working.

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
    <div class='row'>some text</div>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class="imgs">
        </div 
    </div>
</div>
```

I was trying to replicate the scenario in jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/krishnasarma/err1fkcd/) but its not showing the images at all.

Comment: Demo wasn't working, because .imgs div had 0 height: http://jsfiddle.net/err1fkcd/1/

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you haven't specified dimensions for `.imgs` div used for backstretch. Set desired `width` and `height` properties for that container.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/err1fkcd/3/